# Import query for both Realtime Database and Firestore Firebase web v9

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

When importing the query function for Firebase Realtime DB and Firestore, I noticed both query functions have the exact same name.

```
import { query } from "firebase/database";
import { query } from "firebase/firestore";
```

This is mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) in the documentation.

Is this the same function from both places? If not, should I just alias the import of one of the functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an alias for one of the imports. Try:

```js
import { query } from "firebase/database";
import { query as fireQuery } from "firebase/firestore";


const firestoreQuery = fireQuery(...)
```